# Facebook authentication only

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm working on login to discussion on my web using facebook. I finally figured out how to do oauth authorization. But I really don't want extra informations about user, I don't need them and I don't know why should I ask for them. All I need is authentication (user id).

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm an idiot and I was overworked. I realized that user should be able to decline authentication. Sorry for stupid question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be granted basic permissions to get the user's id. This is the minimum amount of permission that a user can grant to you.

You said you have figured out oauth - what method/language are you using? If its JS then you just need this:

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!');
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded and tried run the code from
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk?

They provide sample code, where you can get user id once connected to facebook.

This is how to get the user id:

```
require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                                 'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
                                 'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
                              ));
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```